# Typo3: How to set [FE] [activateContentAdapter] variable to 1

Tags: typo3

How can I change a configuration variable through the backend panel in Typo3?

I need to set this line in the global configuration from

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['activateContentAdapter'] = '';
```

to

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['activateContentAdapter'] = '1';
```

Do I have to use the `installation tool` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backend, go to `Install Tool` > `All Configuration`

Expand `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']`

Check `[FE][activateContentAdapter] = 0`

This solves the distribution.png issue.

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 6.2 the contentAdapter is active on default, if not explicit set to FALSE in your LocalConfiguration.